# What order should I read tales of Mythago Wood?

Tags: suggested-order, fantasy-genre, robert-holdstock

Robert Holdstock thoroughly confused me with his Mythago Wood series, to the point that I gave up trying to understand them. I'm wondering now if I should have read the novels in a different order or if other works have been published (since I abandoned him) that might make it easier for me to make sense of his world.

So, I don't think that the published order is the way to go... Which of his works apply to the Mythago world and what order should I read them to piece his characters' lives together? Thx.

Comment: BTW: The Bone Forest is the last one I read, then gave up.

Comment: I love that you brought this up. I started searching into your question, because I read two Mythago-books years ago, only to discover now that I read Lavondyss, with its title possibly mis-translated as "Mythago Woud"  (= Mythago Woods, I read them in Dutch). Anyway, wikipedia says this about the order: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mythago_Wood#Chronology_of_works_in_the_Mythago_Wood_cycle

Comment: @silvith That list on wikipedia is weird, cuz Lavondyss isn't even included in it and it is definitely a sequel to Mythago Wood.

Comment: @silvith Ah, I figured out how to click-through the chronology on wikipedia. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, answering my own question, I think that I have pieced together some of the threads that link the characters and stories of Mythago wood. Part of my confusion was that I expected sequels to involve the same characters, but many of Holdstock's novels do not. He seems to like to branch off in tangental ways. I had assumed that The Bone Forest was a sequel of Lavondyss since it was published later, but because it is a prequel, it did not bring resolution to any of the questions I had at the end of Lavondyss. Therefore the frustration.

1. **The Bone Forest** introduces the Huxley family - father George, sons Christian and Steven. George Huxley's friend Edward Wynn-Jones goes searching with him in the forest.
2. **Gate of Ivory, Gate of Thorn** focuses on the son, Christian Huxley.
3. **Mythago Wood** tells the tale of Steven Huxley looking for answers about his brother, father, mother, etc. He enlists the help of Anne Hayden (daughter of Edward Wynn-Jones) and Harry Keeton.
4. **Avilion** is about Steven Huxley's life in the forest.
5. **Lavondyss** focuses on Tallis Keeton (younger sister of Harry Keeton). She meets Edward Wynn-Jones in the woods.
6. **The Hollowing** focuses on the Bradley family. Alex Bradley is a friend of Tallis Keeton.

Comment: Not sure that I will take up this series again. It still seems a somewhat jumble. Perhaps too cerebral for me.

Answer (score 2):

I read them in order of publication: Mythago Wood, Lavondyss, The Bone Forest, The Hollowing, Gate of Ivory Gate of Horn. I’m about to read the final book, Avilion. There’s another tangential book about a different woodland in France: Merlin’s Wood. I haven’t read that one.